# Sending a variable outside a function to another function in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to handleSubmit using the place variable

```
<Autocomplete
    onPlaceSelected = { (place) => { 
      console.log(place);
    }}
/>
```

Place is used within that function, but I can't declare a simple variable outside the function using var. How do I do this in react? For some reason everything is a const.

Comment: I don't get it. `place` is a variable of `Autocomplete` component, isn't it? Or it is a variable of the parent of `Autocomplete` ?

Answer (score 0):

As a standard you should avoid writing a large function inline. If all you wanted to do was something simple, like logging, what you've done is fine. However if you want to do more than that, your best bet is to write the method outside of the render component and pass it into the OnPlaceSelected function.

To answer your question though, you can just initialize any variable as you normally would inside a function.

```
<Autocomplete
    onPlaceSelected = { (place) => { 
      var newPlace = place;

      console.log(place);
    }}
/>
```

If this is now what your meaning than my suggestion is that you re-write the question with more of an example of what you're trying to accomplish.